# Connections % of configured limit has gone above 80 from Mongo Atlas

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, loopbackjs, mongodb-atlas

Getting emails from Mongo Atlas that saying `Connections % of configured limit has gone above 80`.

Using M0 Sandbox tier which has 100 max connections.

Whether an upgrade to M2 tier (which has also 100 max connections) solve this?

Comment: I resolved it by deleting all IP whitelist and wait for 5 minutes.  We can monitor that, the connections are decreasing in mongo atlas cluster. At last, it became Zero. Works Added IP whitelist from anywhere to access. Its work fine.

Comment: It seems that you have resolved the symptom once, but how do you prevent it from coming back? I am using it with serverless (Azure Functions) and the connections pile up easily and decrease slowly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved it by deleting all IP whitelist and wait for 5 minutes.

We can monitor that, the connections are decreasing in mongo atlas cluster. At last, it became Zero.

Then added IP whitelist from anywhere to access(Not secure. Just to work. Or whitelist current IP and server Ip).

Its work fine.

Comment: I was just looking around and came at your answer and, well I am not a mongodb atlas expert but IMO, if you're doing this in a prod environment, be really careful with with-listing IPs from anywhere, it could lead to a big security issue/door :/ best !

Answer (score 4):

removing all IP address and waiting 5 minutes works also for me .
seems like it kills all opened connections. Don't forget to allow your ip after that

[see my cluster connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4zlK.png)

there is an opened issue with mongoose. it might be the root cause
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8059